# How to stop browser loading an image or disconnect to a host?

Tags: connection, disconnect

i'm using jQuery to load facebook profile picture and I want the browser disconnect to facebook if the picture can't be loaded after 5 seconds. Here is my code :

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    jQuery('#fbProfilePicture').attr("src","http://graph.facebook.com/100001225080368/picture");
    setTimeout(function(){              
          //my code
          if (true)
          {
            //how to disconnect to facebook here.
          }
          else
          {
            //do something
          }
    },5000);
});
```

I'm using Wordpress. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just set the src attribute to something else. Not very pretty, but since you don't have control over the facebook response not sure how much better it gets. You use jQuery's `load` event to keep track of whether the image has loaded. If it hasn't then just set the src to something else (nothing in my case) or remove the element.

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
    var loaded = false;
    jQuery('#fbProfilePicture').load(function() {
        loaded = true;
    });

    jQuery('#fbProfilePicture').attr("src", "http://graph.facebook.com/100001225080368/picture");

    setTimeout(function() {
        //my code
        if (loaded) {

        } else {
            $('#fbProfilePicture').attr('src', '');
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tested and it didn't works. You can't disconnect by remove "src" attr or set something else to "src" attr. The browser still connect and you will see "Waiting for graph.facebook.com..." on the status bar.

Comment: @newbie29 - I guess you need to set it to an actual image or it doesn't work. Just point it to a transparent gif or something instead. Noticed that I changed `attr` to `prop`. If you use jQuery 1.7+ you should be using prop instead. http://jsfiddle.net/Te5Nm/

Comment: Thank you. I found my problem. The browser continue connecting to facebook beacause another javascript function on my page. With the script above, we can use "removeAttr" or set 'src' empty by using '.attr' or 'prop' as your noticed. Thanks again :D